# Динамическое изменение стиля класса через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

И так. У нас имеется сумма денег, которая приходит на страничку в виде переменной `$val["NSUM"]`, которая находится внутри foreach. То есть доступ к ней у меня не сразу же.

В зависимости от того больше она нуля или нет, изменяется background-color div'a.

Имеется css файл с начальным значением background-color'a для этого класса div.

```
<div class="sale-personal-account-wallet-list-container">
    <?
    foreach($arResult["ACCOUNT_LIST"] as $val)
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var sum = '<?=$val["NEW_INFO"]['NSUM'];?>';
                if (sum < 0)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('sale-personal-account-wallet-list-container')[0].style= 'background-color: #ea8887 !important';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('sale-personal-account-wallet-list-container')[0].style= 'background-color: #65c77a !important';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div class="sale-personal-account-wallet-list-item">
            <span class="sale-personal-account-wallet-sum"><?=$val["NEW_INFO"]['SUM']?></span>
            <span class="sale-personal-account-wallet-currency"><?=$val["NEW_INFO"]['CURRENCY']?></span>
        </div>
        <?
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Скрипт срабатывает, значение цвета меняется, но не сразу: сначала подгружается изначальный цвет, который в css и только через ~0.5 секунд нужный мне.

Как сделать так, чтобы нужный цвет появлялся сразу же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение достаточно простое - скрыть элемент до полной прогрузки скрипта. Т.е. изначально элемент скрыт (display:none), а вот в вашей функции на onload он после всех вычислений становится видимым (display:block например).

К тому же в вашем примере я бы посоветовал переделать foreach т.к. для каждого элемента будет создаваться своя копия `<script>` что может вызвать путаницу при большом кол-во элементов в массиве. Лучше заранннее вычислить все элементы `<?=$val["NEW_INFO"]['NSUM'];?>';`как `{bool,SUM,CURRENCY}` объект и поместить их в массив. А уже сам массив обрабатывать внутри JS. Получится 2 цикла (второй в самом js) но конструкция в целом будет в одном `<script>`

Comment: <script> вынести из foreach? Немного не понял

Comment: Ну имеется ввиду что ваша конструкция foreach каждый раз генерирует не только разметку html но и блок script. Причем абсолютно одинакового содержания. Например 4 шага foreach - 4 блока script прямо в html. Это немного не рационально и нарушает DRY (по крайней мере с точки зрения JS).

Comment: Ну вообще туда приходит один элемент массива [0] и меняться это вряд ли будет, так как законченный компонент.

Comment: Ну тогда странное решение использовать foreach там где ожидается один элемент (разве что если массив может быть пустым). Но в целом это был просто совет ( не just do it ) ^_^

Comment: А без участия JS можно как-то сделать?

Comment: ну можно и без js попробовать ( не уверен). Можно сделать css правило с нужным стилем, и поставить условие нужный див как например вы сделали тут `var sum = <?=$val["NEW_INFO"]['NSUM'];?>`. Т.е. `<?=if (val>0) someCssStyle else ""?>`. Я не уверен т.к. неуверен что можно влиять так на саму верстку (этот код надо вставить внутри class `class="вот сюда" `

Comment: Но одно но - если данные грузятся не сразу, то такая обработка может не прокатить

Comment: Ну да, цикл ведь внутри изменяемого Div'a

Comment: Распечатал нормально приходящие данные и понял, что сглупил.
Изменение класса стилей вынес в начало документа.